# Check header row of Excel sheet for particular column

Tags: excel, powershell

I have over 150 excel files where some have an extra column (let's call it "ExtraColumn"), while some do not have this column. Instead of opening each file manually to see which ones have the extra column, I want to use powershell to figure it out.

The code I have tried so far hasn't seemed to have gotten me anywhere. If you have any suggestions or can point me to the correct answer, that would be very wonderful and much appreciated!

```
gci -Path C:\Test -Recurse | % {
    $ExcelFile = (Get-Content $_.FullName -TotalCount 1)

    if ($ExcelFile -like "ExtraColumn") {
        Write-Host "$_ has the extra column"
    } else {
        Write-Host "$_ does not have the extra column" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Excel workbooks are binary files. `Get-Content` is for reading text files and doesn't understand the structure of Excel workbooks. Do you perhaps mean CSVs when you say "Excel sheets"? Or do you have actual workbooks and need a way to process them?

Comment: If these are actual .xlsx-files you will not be able to read them like plain text files. You'd have to extract the contents using 7zip or such and then find whatever xml-file within that has this info. The sound way to go about this would most likely be using an Excel COM-object instead.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean sheets. I have 150 excel files that are all XLS format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Excel ComObject, for the code simplicity just name the sheet otherwise you can find the sheet as well, add foreach section to run it on all files,

For the example i named the column - 'extracol'

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$WB = $excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\exceltest.xlsx') 
$WS = $Excel.WorkSheets.item("Sheet1")

$ExtraCol = ($ws.Columns.Find('extracol'))
if ($ExtraCol) {$ExtraCol.Delete()}
$wb.Save()
$wb.Close()
$excel.Quit()
```